# WSO2EMM (MDM) Profile Installation Failed - Certificate is invalid

Tags: ios, linux, certificate, wso2, mdm

I followed the documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/General+Server+Configurations) to generate the certificate and depoly the iOS agent but when I try to setup the certificate I have this error

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/401x713q90/539/YiGuh8.png

So I sent an email to WSO2 company to help me to solve this issue and they respond
" The iOS Server Configurations [1] in EMM documentation has been updated with an extra step to generate version 3 format certificates. Step 2 now mentions how to modify the openssl.cnf file so that it will generate version 3 format of CA and RA certificates."

So I re-followed the updated documentation and I received the same error.

Comment: From the error image that you have uploaded, the MDM profile is still not trusted. In order to install a MDM profile to an iOS device, the profile needs to be signed by a trusted certificate or the Root certificate of the certificate which is used to sign the MDM profile needs to be installed into the device.

Comment: Please follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations) to generate all the certificates. Then when you create a new user, the link to download the agent app will be displayed. In that link, there will be two buttons, one to download the Root certificate and the other to download the agent.